# Junit testing forcing exception

Tags: exception, logging, junit

I have the following method:

```
public Object method(){
 try
 {
      privatevoidmethod1();
      privatevoidmethod2();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
      Log.debug(e);
 }
  return object;
}
```

How do I force the exception so I can test the debug call?

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside how you'd test the debug call, you'd normally trigger an exception by providing suitable inputs such that an exception would be created/thrown. If that's not suitable, the alternative is to provide a substitute (mocked) component that has been configured/written to throw an exception e.g.

```
public MyClass(MyInjectedComponent component) {
   this.component = component;
}
```

and you'd provide for your test an implementation of `MyInjectedComponent` that will throw an exception (for testing purposes). The approach of injecting components into other components is called [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) and worth investigating.

I'd normally use a mocking framework for this (e.g. [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or similar). However a trivial implementation of the above could be:

```
public class MyImplementationForTesting extends MyInjectedComponent {
   public void method() throws Exception {
      throw new Exception();
   }
}
```

Comment: I do have a test that throws the exception and I can successfully assert it. But what if I need to assert that the log statement is being called?

Comment: I would mock the logging component and inject it